# C++ - 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++, outofrangeexception

Although I've wrapped the try code around every part of my program I can't get the line that causes the runtime error (without any other details):

```
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  vector::_M_range_check Aborted"
```

and I don't know what I am supposed to do.
The error is caused by following piece of code, since it appears after addition of these lines:

```
.....
map<int, StaticObject*>::iterator mapPos2;
vector<StaticObject*, boost::pool_allocator<StaticObject*> >::iterator vecPos;

map<int, int>::iterator mapPos = userCountMap.begin();  

mapPos2 = this->_cachedObjects.find(this->_lruQueue.at(mapPos->first)->getId());                   
vecPos = find(this->_lruQueue.begin(),this->_lruQueue.end(), this->_lruQueue.at(mapPos->first));

size -= this->_lruQueue.at(mapPos->first)->getSize();  
_availableSpace += this->_lruQueue.at(mapPos->first)->getSize(); 

delete (*mapPos2).second;   

this->_cachedObjects.erase(mapPos2); 
this->_lruQueue.erase(vecPos);  
............
```

and later on:

```
map<int, int> userCountMap;

userCountMap.insert(make_pair(object->getId(),1)); ...
this->userCountMap[id]++; ...
this->userCountMap.clear(); ....
```

Comment: -1 WTH is unclear from this exception and tracking (debugging) the point where it was thrown??

Answer (score 2):

`std::out_of_range` is thrown by `std::vector::at` if the index is out of range of valid values (that is, `[0..size-1]`).

Try wrapping the lines calling that function with `try/catch` blocks and see which one throws. Then, fire up your debugger and find out why the index is out of range.